# Find dynamically added data attribute via .find() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append a value to my HTML body via the `.append()` function. Later on I need to retrieve this value but I cannot because it is dynamically added. I searched for the cause and found out that I have to use `.find()`. But even with this method I'm not able to grab the string. Do you eventually see my mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // data[0] = "Tesla X"
    $("body").append('<div id="myCar" data-car="' + data[0] + '"></div>');

    $(document).on('click', '#save', function(e){  
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var page0    = $(this).data('car');  
        var page1    = $('body').find('[data-car]');
        var page2    = $('myCar').find('[data-car]');  
        var page3    = $(document.getElementById('[data-car]')); 
        var page4    = $('#body').find('.bottom').data('car');
        var page5    = $('body').find('.bottom').data('car');
        var page6    = $('body').find('[data-car]');
        var page7    = $('body').find('#myCar').data('data-car');
        console.log(page0);  // not working -> undefined 
        console.log(page1);  // not working -> Object { 0: <div#myCar>, length: 1, prevObject: Object } 
        console.log(page2);  // not working -> Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object } 
        console.log(page3);  // not working -> Object {  } 
        console.log(page4);  // not working -> undefined 
        console.log(page5);  // not working -> undefined 
        console.log(page6);  // not working -> Object { 0: <div#myCar>, length: 1, prevObject: Object } 
        console.log(page7);  // not working -> undefined 
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried simple `$('#myCar').data('car')`/$('#myCar').attr('data-car')? and `$('body').find('[data-car]')` is giving you result so try `$('body').find('[data-car]').data('car')`

Comment: Shouldn't `$('myCar')` be `$('#myCar')`?

Comment: Please put the relevant markup in your snippet as well so that we can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see why its not working from the snippet comment

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // data[0] = "Tesla X"
    $("body").append('<div id="myCar" data-car="' + data[0] + '"></div>');

    $(document).on('click', '#save', function(e){  
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var page0    = $(this).data('car');  //invalid attribute its target the clicked element not data-car element
        var page1    = $('body').find('[data-car]');//valid one.you are get the element object only
        var page2    = $('myCar').find('[data-car]');  //invalid one missing id mention from beginig `#`
        var page3    = $(document.getElementById('[data-car]')); //invalid jquery object.you are confusing jquery object and js 
        var page4    = $('#body').find('.bottom').data('car');//body its tag not a id name
        var page5    = $('body').find('.bottom').data('car'); //bottom class not in a html
        var page6    = $('body').find('[data-car]'); //its same like page2
        var page7    = $('body').find('#myCar').data('data-car'); //already you are calling the data() function.so its get invalid attribute value .its searching like `data-data-car`

      var page8=$('body').find('[data-car]').data('car')//correct one

      console.log(page0);  // not working -> undefined 
        console.log(page1);  // not working -> Object { 0: <div#myCar>, length: 1, prevObject: Object } 
        console.log(page2);  // not working -> Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object } 
        console.log(page3);  // not working -> Object {  } 
        console.log(page4);  // not working -> undefined 
        console.log(page5);  // not working -> undefined 
        console.log(page6);  // not working -> Object { 0: <div#myCar>, length: 1, prevObject: Object } 
        console.log(page7);  // not working -> undefined 
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation on each variable. This helps me alot. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var data = "Tesla X"
     $("body").append('<div id="myCar" data-car="' + data + '"></div>');

     var page0   = $(document).find('#myCar');
     console.log(page0);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the element :

```
var elem = $('#myCar')
```

To retrieve its attribute  :

```
$('#myCar').attr("data-car")
```

Finally :

```
var value = $('#myCar').attr("data-car") //Value == Tesla X
```